# Duplicate W-2 from employer with different validation id

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-2

My previous employer sent me two W-2s for this year. Neither is a W-2C. All of the information on them is the same, except for the verification/validation number and batch number. All attempts to contact them about this have failed. When I plug it into Turbotax, it is able to auto-populate the information from the W-2 with the higher batch number (which leads me to believe that batch number is somehow tied to date).

There's a help link about what to do if you received two W-2s from your employer, which states to just enter each one of them, but when I do this, I go from a $4500 return to a $150 bill, and it seems to indicate that I made twice what I actually made last year.

Should I disregard the W-2 that wasn't auto-populated (the one with the lower batch number)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I disregard the W-2 that wasn't auto-populated (the one with the lower batch number)?

[Intuit](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/1901658-how-do-i-handle-multiple-w-2s-from-the-same-employer) says **yes**:

> If your W-2s are identical down to the last number and letter, you can either keep the duplicate with your tax records or securely destroy it. Don't enter them both.

Referencing [this](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw2.pdf) example W-2, I don't see a field for verification, validation, or batch number so that is probably an unofficial number used by the company who prepared the form. If this is the case, then the forms are identical and you should ignore the other one.